# What's the different between upload a zip file and jar file to aws lambda? Why zip file doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to upload my lambda code to aws lambda console, which can be trigger by another Amazon services, but the problem is, my jar file is pretty big, more than 50MB, because is production code, has many libraries, so I can't upload a jar file. The zip file is about 300KB, but when I upload the zip file, it keeps showing error "Class not found: EventHandler".

I test it with a simple project which only has lambda stuff no other dependencies, when I upload the jar file and test it, it works, but when I upload zip file, I got error "Class not found: EventHandler"

What's the different upload a zip file and jar file to aws lambda? How to resolve my issue?

```
package myService.lambda

public class EventHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String>{

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
        
    }
}
```

[image]

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: EventHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically Java projects that use the Java Lambda run-time API are packaged into a JAR. If your JAR is larger than 50 MB, you can't upload it directly. However, you can upload it to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket and then point Lambda to the object via the console. See:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I got that error above, but my jar file is 150MB, which is smaller than 262144000 bytes, why does it happened?

Comment: Did you try to upload it via an Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: I edited the screenshot, I upload it to s3, and then try to upload from s3

Comment: So - it works as a JAR, but you get the error when its a ZIP?

Comment: I uploaded the jar file, and this error, not sure why I got this error

Comment: For your project - do you have a GIT project. I would like to see what is happening

Comment: In my projects - i build via "mvn  package" command.  This results in a JAR file that has no issue being deployed as a Lambda function, as shown here:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels

Comment: How did you build your Java project ?

Comment: Hi, I successful upload the jar through s3 after mvn package, but when I test it, I got ClassNotFoundException, I think the handler name is correct, what can be the issue?

Comment: Yes -- that could be the issue.  Ensure that you setup your project - including the Java run-time POM dependencies, the Lambda fully qualified names, including the proper Handler class name(s),  etc  as described in that AWS tutorial.